# Invisible Control becomes Visible when closing page Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a frame, the IsVisible is binded to a property in my model view that is set to false. when I change the flyout in my shell, the frame makes an appearance as the shell flyout is closing. Any idea why this is happening ?

```
         // in my model view this is the property
         public bool ShowPanel{ get { return _showPanel; } set { _showPanel = 
         value; OnPropertyChange(); } }
                

         // in my view this is the panel

        <Frame IsVisible="{Binding ShowPanel}"  BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="Purple"             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" WidthRequest="100"  HeightRequest="200" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,200,250">
            <local:ExtendedListView  ItemTapped="ExtendedListView_ItemTapped"  ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" IsVisible="{Binding ShowPanel}" SelectionMode="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"  BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <local:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Image.Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"  x:DataType="local1:ServiceLayers"></Image>
                                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" Color="Purple" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:DataType="local1:ServiceLayers"></CheckBox>
                                <Label Padding="-5,0,0,0"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Text="{Binding Name}" x:DataType="local1:Service"></Label>


                                <Label></Label>
                            </Grid>

                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate>
            </local:ExtendedListView>
        </Frame>


       // In the View Class 
       protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() {

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It could be that the page binding context is removed before the page animates away. You could define [binding fallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-fallbacks) to ensure the panel is hidden unless you explicitly set `ShowPanel` to `true`.

Comment: My first guess is that the code does exactly what it is told to do. Put a breakpoint on ShowPanel setter. (Easier to do if you move the setter in source to its own line of code. I mean, add a carriage return before `set`.) What calls it, while the flyout is closing/changing?

Comment: @AndrewH That is exactly what I am doing, I am resetting the ContextBinding On Disappear, so probably this is what is causing it to re appear for a split second. I've set a fallback value, and now it never shows. You should put that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the BindingContext is removed/changed as you navigate away from the page, the Frame would appear as the binding is invalidated and updated by the binding engine. You have two options:

1. Don't manually clear the BindingContext from the page as the navigation lifecycle and GC should clean up those resources on their own.
2. Use [binding fallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-fallbacks) to define behavior when the binding source can't be resolved (because you've nulled the BindingContext) or the binding source is resolved but the bound property is null.